Solving the Issue of Multiple API Calls Triggering Script Execution
experiencing an issue in my React application where refreshing the browser causes multiple API calls to be made to the backend, resulting in the Puppeteer script being executed multiple times. This is causing unnecessary load on the backend and slowing down the application.
Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I'm using React with a functional component that fetches data from the backend API on mount.

The API call is made using the useEffect hook with an empty dependency array.

The Puppeteer script is triggered by the API call and runs a headless browser instance to perform some tasks.
src/components/NewsFeed.jsx:


import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getNews } from '../../apiClient/apiClient';
import Cardcomp from './Card';

const NewsFeed = () => {
    const [news, setNews] = useState({});
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Fetching news on component mount');
        setIsLoading(true);
        const fetchNews = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await getNews();
                setNews(response);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error.message);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };
    
        fetchNews();
    }, []); 
    
    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
    }
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    
    if (!news.coindesk || !news.dailycoin) {
        return null; // Return null to prevent rendering the card component
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>News Feed</h2>
            <ul>
               <li>
                    <Cardcomp name="CoinDes" title={news.coindesk.title} para={news.coindesk.para} /> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Cardcomp name="DailyCoin" title={news.dailycoin.title} para={news.dailycoin.para} />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
   
};

export default NewsFeed;

Backend code :
index.js:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const { scrapeCoinDesk, scrapeDailyCoin } = require('./script.js');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const app = express();
const port = 3000;


app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/scrape', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Scrape API called');
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

        const results = await Promise.all([
            scrapeCoinDesk(browser),
            scrapeDailyCoin(browser),
        ]);

        await browser.close();

        res.json({
            coindesk: results[0],
            dailycoin: results[1],
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during scraping:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to scrape data' });
    }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

server/script.js:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

async function scrapeCoinDesk(browser) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.coindesk.com/', { timeout: 60000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('.featured-cardstyles__FeaturedCardWrapper-sc-caozbq-2 .card-title h3');
    const title = await page.$eval('.featured-cardstyles__FeaturedCardWrapper-sc-caozbq-2 .card-title h3', el => el.textContent.trim());
    await page.waitForSelector('.featured-cardstyles__FeaturedCardWrapper-sc-caozbq-2 .featured-cardstyles__FeaturedCardDescription-sc-caozbq-0 p');
    const para = await page.$eval('.featured-cardstyles__FeaturedCardWrapper-sc-caozbq-2 .featured-cardstyles__FeaturedCardDescription-sc-caozbq-0 p', el => el.textContent.trim());
    await page.close();
    return { title, para };
}

async function scrapeDailyCoin(browser) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://dailycoin.com/', { timeout: 60000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('.post-content-wrapper .dc-title-link');
    const title = await page.$eval('.post-content-wrapper .dc-title-link', el => el.textContent.trim());
    await page.waitForSelector('.post-content-wrapper .post-excerpt p');
    const para = await page.$eval('.post-content-wrapper .post-excerpt p', el => el.textContent.trim());
    await page.close();
    return { title, para };
}
module.exports = { scrapeCoinDesk, scrapeDailyCoin  };

When I refresh the browser, I expect the API call to be made only once, but instead, I see multiple requests being sent to the backend, and the Puppeteer script is executed multiple times. This behavior is consistent across different browsers and devices.
I've tried debugging the issue by reviewing the code, checking console logs, and using the browser's debugger, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of the problem.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue? What could be causing the multiple API calls and Puppeteer script executions on browser refresh? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? (console logs count too). Are you running in strict mode in development, or is this in production?

where is NewsFeed being rendered?  is it possible that it is being rerendered, perhaps as a result of the api call?
